# PowerBI connection to Spark Delta Lake

Tags: apache-spark, powerbi, delta-lake

I am trying to connect the PowerBI Desktop (running on Windows) to the delta lake table in a Spark Cluster (running on Linux).

I've mounted the delta lake table folder (with parque files) to Windows box via Samba. Now, how should I add a data source and/or a query to access the Delta Table?

I was following the instruction in this link: https://github.com/delta-io/connectors/tree/master/powerbi, however, the sample was only for the Azure Blob content.

Is there a way to specify the delta lake table resides on a local folder?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is the solution that I was struggling with. I am a newbie in PowerBI space.

Use "Folder.Files(" to replace the "AzureStorage.Blobs(" part.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/folder-files